# Trying to download atmospheric data from Copernicus with Python ->"requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error:"

Tags: python, error-handling, download

I'm trying to download the atmospheric dataset from Copernicus ( https://ads.atmosphere.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/cams-global-reanalysis-eac4?tab=form) but I've been getting this error ([Picture attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sD5ip.jpg))!!

The code I'm trying to run (provided directly by Copernicus website):

```
import cdsapi

c = cdsapi.Client()

c.retrieve(
    'cams-global-reanalysis-eac4',
    {
        'format': 'netcdf',
        'variable': [
            'particulate_matter_10um', 'particulate_matter_2.5um',
        ],
        'date': '2016-12-01/2021-12-31',
        'time': [
            '00:00', '03:00', '06:00',
            '09:00', '12:00', '15:00',
            '18:00', '21:00',
        ],
        'area': [
            -25.35, -49.39, -25.64,
            -49.19,
        ],
    },
    'download.nc'
)
```

I'm really having a hard time trying to get this dataset! Thank you so very much for your help!!!

Comment: hey I want to try, but it looks like you need an api key. I think the steps on the git repo are pretty good though. I'd try their toy example then do something more complicated https://github.com/ecmwf/cdsapi

Comment: Hii, thank you very much! Yes, exactly.. I tried to do that, actually! They say you must create a ".cdsapirc" file, with the information (api key), and place it in your directory. Did I understand it correclty?

Comment: yes, so that would just be creating a file in your home directory `cd ~` with the following contents ```url: https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/api/v2
key: <UID>:<API key>
verify: 0```